# Give default value for auto_increment for more than one column in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, html, sql, servlets

When I am trying to execute the following query

```
create table xyz(id int(3) not null auto_increment, name char(10) not null, code int(6) auto_increment=2000);
```

I am getting the following error :

```
You have an error near '=2000)'
```

I want the id column to start from 1, which it will start but at the same time i want code column to be incremented starting from 2000 whenever I insert data into the table.
so, Is it possible to have two auto_increments in the query? I am doing this with the help of a servlet.

Comment: As MySQL manual clearly says, there can only be one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in a table, and it has to be `PRIMARY KEY` (or part of it), also, the correct syntax for setting atuo-increment value is after the table definition has ended (at the same place you specify ENGINE and COMMENTS)

Comment: Any particular reason for not adding 2000 to the id column for the other desired column?  It seems like a static offset from the row id value.

Comment: i want to use id for primary key reference and i am doing a java servlet program in which i have to generate a random number whenever i submit a form to be stored in the database, so i thought of giving default value and then incrementing it again whenever data is inserted

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but that doesn't sounds like a *Random* number.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer: you can not have multiple auto_increment values, just as poncha said.

However, this can be done a couple ways:

1. Rewrite your insert statement to find the previous code and add 1:

   INSERT INTO xyz (name, code) VALUES ("some-name", 
   (SELECT max(code)+1 FROM xyz))
2. Create a mysql trigger after an insert to find the max value for code and add one then update

!! I don't recommend this at all, please redesign your code !!

My highest recommendation would be to generate a random number and use that when inserting, or rewrite the subquery to create a random number.

Comment: Keep in mind, databases are used to store information. The code (java) is used to manipulate/use the data. Oh and java == :(